# How to use the querybuilder in doctrine to test whether or not atleast one of two given values is already set in the database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a table called `Code`, which has an `id`, `code` and a `creationDate`.

Let's assume I have an object, which I want to insert into this table, but I want to check whether or not there already is an object that has either the same `id` set or the same `code`.

I already figured out that it's not possible to accomplish this with `findBy()` or `findByOne()` and that I most likely have to use the QueryBuilder.

There are a couple of things though that I can't understand. Im actually surprised that I can't find an answer on that in the whole web...

First, this is my current query code:

```
$query = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()->select('id', 'X')->from('Code', 'X')->where('id = 3');
```

As you can see, I wrote 'X' twice. Can someone please tell me what that is? Because I have to set it somehow. The `from()` method needs atleast two arguments. I read that it is some kind of alias, but why do I need to declare that and which purpose does it have? Also I'm almost 100% sure that there are syntax errors, too. (My IDE unfortunately doesn't mark syntax errors or similar, but that's something different.) I would really appreciate if someone could take a few minutes to explain this to me.

Also, once I declared my `$query`, I have to execute it or what? I really have no idea how this works. I'm sorry, I really feel stupid for not getting this most likely simple thing...

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to simply prevent from saving 2 records which have either the same `id`or `code`? If so, did you take a look at the `UniqueEntity` constraint? [UniqueEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)

Comment: Yes, but I want to check for that inside of my code. A constraint would not help me there.

Comment: And what isn't working using `findBy()`?

Comment: You can't use `findBy()` because that would require one `findBy()` per condition?

Comment: Correct. I could of course do two queries, but I want to do only one for performance reasons.

Comment: And you can only say findby(array("id" => "value")), so no multiple conditions like findby(array("id" => "value" OR "code" => "codeValue")). Atleast to my knowledge.

Comment: Posted an answer, let me know if it helped. Not sure about your `code` field type though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Doctrine - The QueryBuilder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html)
First, you need to do `->getQuery()->getResult()` after your creating the query. This is what will yield you the results.

But you could also use this to return only a count since you just want to know if there's a "conflicting" record.

Also, there's no need to declare an alias since you are including only 1 entity.

**Edit:**
Added the parameters after OP's comment.

```
$result = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c')
    ->from(CodeEntity::class, 'c')
    // Either go with 2 where clauses
    ->where('c.id = :codeId')
    ->orWhere('c.code = :codeCode')
    // Or you could go with a one-liner for the where clause
    //->where('c.id = :codeId or c.code = :codeCode')
    ->setParameters([
        'codeId' => $code->getId(),
        'couponCode' => $code->getCodeCode()
    ])
    ->getQuery() 
    ->getScalarResult()
```

Comment: Okay, have to try that tommorow. Can you tell me what an alias actually is? Thank you!

Comment: For the alias, see the doc: [Doctrine Query Language](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-clause)

Comment: If i try this now it tells me that its missing the 'from' keyword. What would I have to pass as parameters? :S

Comment: Edited my answer, I thought you could omit the `->from()`... Can't check in my project currently. Will have to verify tomorrow.

Comment: Alright, I finally got it. My solution is similar to yours: $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()->select('c')
            ->from(CodeEntity::class, 'c')
            ->where('c.id = :codeId')
            ->orWhere('c.code = :codeCode')
            ->setParameter('codeId', $code->getId())
            ->setParameter('couponCode', $code->getCodeCode())
            ->getQuery()
            ->getScalarResult()) {
                // ...
                return;

Comment: Best formatting ... sorry. But I will mark your answer as the most helpful. Helped a lot still. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer by adding the parameters (I went with a general query, forgot to add the parameters! Oops!). Also, you'll see in my answer that you can go with `->setParameters()` which allow you to define an array of parameters. Also, you can go with a one line where clause if you prefer, but I find the 2 lines where clause to have better readability. And I'm not sure if one is really better than the other.